# mysql got executed but not showing results

Tags: mysql, set

The below is getting executed but not showing results why

```
SET @skillArray1 =  'ccc,php';
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skillName IN (@skillArray1);
```

Comment: What is the data type of column skillname? is it a string? perhaps you should use "LIKE" instead of "IN" ?

Answer (score 0):

On comma separated values as a *single string*, `IN` will not always return correct result. You have to treat the CSV string as a *set of values*. And in `MySQL` we have [*`FIND_IN_SET`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to search specific value within that set.

Use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SET @skillArray1 = 'ccc,php'; 

SELECT * FROM skills WHERE FIND_IN_SET( skillName, @skillArray1 );
```